# PHP Parser - Copy next line(?)

Tags: php, html, parsing, simple-html-dom

Im trying to parse data from a website using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser". I have a different implementation that sometimes doesnt work. (I will post it at the end)

Ideally, I would like to find word "Online:" in the html document and copy the next line.

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td class="tb_1">Online:</td>
    <td class="tb_2">offline</td>
</tr>
```

It should find "Online:" and copy "offline".

---

This is my current implementation. It creates an array of elements that have "tr" tag. However, that number seems to change so sometimes element 19 isnt what Im looking for.

```
<?php
    include ('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.guildstats.eu/character?nick=GRUBY%20FESTYNIARZ');

    $element = $html->find("tr");
    echo $element[19];
?>
```

If you need more information (the website etc), just post and Ill add it.

---

Edit: Lots of help! Thank you very much! I have to go out now but when I come back im going to implement one of the solutions!

Comment: What have you attempted and what debugging have you done with that line?

Comment: why not searching for text/class rather than guessing a key

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($element)`?

Comment: are you _actually_ writing your own parser, or rather: are you writing a wrapper around `DOMDocument` and/or `simpleXML`? Either way, why wrap something, and not change the actual API (by much)

Comment: Why are you searching for `tr`? Don't you want to search for `td`? Then loop through all of them, check if the text is `Online`, ad when you find it go to the next and and get its text.

Comment: Barmar, yes you are totally right. I just changed to searching for td. Do i just need to loop through the array and find my desired text?

Comment: Either Barmar's solution will work, or you can proceed this way: Is it always the last row of the table ? If yes, then use: `end($html->find("#tab1 tr tb_2"))->plaintext;` to get the specified content...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need external libraries to do that...

Simply load the dom with PHP board tools as string using file_get_contents()...

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://www.guildstats.eu/character?nick=GRUBY%20FESTYNIARZ');
```

And then simply find the entire  tag which should be unique on the page:

```
if(stripos($content, 'Sorry! Guild or character does not exsists') === false) {
    if(stripos($content, '<td class="tb_2">offline</td>') !== false) {
        //Your character is offline
    } else {
        //Your character is online
    }
} else {
    //A character with this name does not exist at all
}
```

By the way: Cool to find people involved in to tibia at stackoverflow. ;)

Comment: Thanks, going to try that out! By the way im doing this for my friend :)

Comment: @Szlose be careful with this, sometimes if the server is configured correctly you will not be able to use file_get_contents

Comment: @up, yeah but this is the easiest way to try first. if you find such a well guarded server you might have other troubles fetching content aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Use next_sibling:

```
$html->find('td[text=Online:]', 0)->next_sibling->text();
```

Answer (score -2):

Why don`t you use xpath to retrieve what you need. Your code should be something like this:

```
<?php
    include ('simple_html_dom.php');
    $html = file_get_html('http://www.guildstats.eu/character?nick=GRUBY%20FESTYNIARZ');

    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($html);

    $result = $xml->xpath('/tr/td[. ="Online"]');

    while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
       echo $node."\n";
    } 
?>
```

For more information about xpath you can check here:

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php

Comment: Where are you searching for `Online`?

Comment: modified with the online solution

Comment: `$html =...SimpleXMLElement($string)`